# Can i recall an email I sent using sendmail on Solaris?

Tags: unix, email, solaris

The option to recall a message seems to be only available on MS Office Outlook. 
Has anyone tried recalling a message sent by sendmail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are referring to belongs to the MS Exchange (i.e. mail server not MS Outlook - the client). And it only works for the messages sent to local accounts hosted on the same Exchange server. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/how-message-recall-works-HA001091760.aspx